# Synfony3 Console: Add own helper to HelperSet

Tags: symfony, symfony-console

Is there a way to add own helpers to the console HelperSet in Symfony3?

I didn't find any helpful thing in the documentation.

Comment: It's rather simple to find just by following the code isn't it? `bin/console` uses `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application`, which extends `Symfony\Component\Console\Application`, which has a method called `getDefaultHelperSet`. Implement your own Application class, extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application`, override `getDefaultHelperSet` and use that in your `bin/console`.

Comment: Thank you i followed the code and find the set() method. Works great. :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i followed the code and find a simple solution. :)

I just have to add my class that implements the HelperInterface, or extend the abstract Helper class.

```
$this->getHelperSet()->set(new MyHelper(), 'myhelper');
```

And myhelper class looks like that:

```
<?php
namespace MyApp\Helper;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Helper;

class MyHelper extends Helper
{
    /**
     * @param $string
     * @return string
     */
    public function doIt($string) {
        return 'this is your '.$string;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the canonical name of this helper.
     *
     * @return string The canonical name
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'myhelper';
    }
}
```

And in my code i can use it like:

```
$myhelper = $this->helperSet->get('myhelper');
$myString = $myhelper->doIt('hallo');
```

:)